# Fortran error: Error: Non-numeric character in statement at label (1)

Tags: fortran, fortran95

This is my program

```
 Subroutine( m,n, bb,AA)
 integer::m,n 

Real bb(m),AA(m,n)

   print*,'enter b value'
 read*,bb
print*,'enter A value'
 read *,AA

Print*, bb
Print *, AA
end
```

This is the error, how to solve it;

**Compiler Output:**

```
   YCbT17Kz.f:1.2:

    Subroutine( m,n, bb,AA)
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:1.2:

    Subroutine( m,n, bb,AA)
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:2.2:

    integer::m,n
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:2.2:

    integer::m,n
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:4.1:

    Real bb(m),AA(m,n)
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:4.1:

    Real bb(m),AA(m,n)
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:6.4:

    print*,'enter b value'
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:6.4:

    print*,'enter b value'
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:7.2:

    read*,bb
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:7.2:

    read*,bb
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:8.1:

    print*,'enter A value'
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:8.1:

    print*,'enter A value'
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:9.2:

    read *,AA
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:9.2:

    read *,AA
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:11.1:

    Print*, bb
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:11.1:

    Print*, bb
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:12.1:

    Print *, AA
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:12.1:

    Print *, AA
    1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:13.1:

    end
    1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
    YCbT17Kz.f:13.1:

    end
    1

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Comment: @Barmar The edit was helpful, but the question is very likely a result of using fixed-form source (where formatting is crucial).  Could you please recheck?  amanygooda - could you also please check that the formatting is correct?  [It may be, and the answer is that you're telling the compiler it's fixed-form when it isn't.]

Comment: @francescalus right I approved the edit because it is fortran95 and because the first error is source form independent, but the other errors suggest the fixed source form.

Comment: I have use online compiler,so, I don't know from where my mistake come. can you explain more about the sentence it self

Comment: @VladimirF To be honest, I saw the error message and the `.f` suffix and stopped there.  (+1 for the more thorough answer.)

Answer (score 3):

```
   Subroutine( m,n, bb,AA)
```

is not a valid Fortran syntax. The language requires

```
   Subroutine name_of_the_subroutine(m, n, bb, AA)
```

The error message

```
Real bb(m),AA(m,n)
1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
YCbT17Kz.f:4.1:
```

suggests you are probably using the fixed source form where a numeric label is expected in columns 1-5. The statement itself must start at column 7 or later. But I can imagine it could be a consequence of a previous error.

The best thing is to try to correct the first error and rename the file to have the suffix `.f90` which denotes the free form source as @francescalus suggests in the comment. It is quite possible it will reveal other errors, which you might want to solve yourself or ask a new question about them.

If the online compiler does not allow changing the file name you can try forcing the free form source by a compiler option such as -ffree-form for gfortran and similar for other compilers.

Comment: For completeness on the source form (after correcting the invariant syntax error): consider renaming the file to `.f90` (or use compiler options for free-form source).